# How to access a cssText of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner with javascript, so sorry if my question is very elementary, but I cannot find a solution for my code. What I'm trying to do is that: I have a Card with a list of href element. When the user clicks on the link, I add dynamically other card in the page and then I hide the `<a>` element for prevent a double click from the user with

```
$$('#idLinkToHide').hide();
```

What I cannot to do is to show a message when there are not link to click inside my card..when all links are hidden.
I tried to do that in this way.

this is my html:

```
<div class="accordion-item">
   <a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title">Menu Select</div>
      </div>
   </a>
   <div class="accordion-item-content">
      <div class="list">
          <ul>
            <li><!-- this is the div where I'd like to show the message--> 
                <div id="messageAccordion"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a  href="javascript:addCard1();" class="link" id="linkAd1">
                <div class="item-media"><i class="f7-icons">add_round_fill </i></div>
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-title">Add Canel 1</div>
                  </div>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="javascript:addCard2();" class="link" id="linkAd2">
                <div class="item-media"><i class="f7-icons">add_round_fill</i></div>
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-title">Add Card 2</div>
                  </div>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="javascript:addCard3();" class="link button-round" id="linkAllevamenti">
                <div class="item-media"><i class="f7-icons">add_round_fill </i></div>
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="item-title">add Card 3</div>
                  </div>
              </a>
            </li>

           <!-- other <li><li> element -->
          </ul>
      </div>
   </div><!--accordion-content-->
</div><!--accordion-->
```

To achieve the task, I tried to retrieve all `<a>` element inside the accordion-item-content then calculate how many links there are inside, calculate the links hidden and finally do the comparison to check if all link are hidden or not... however after I retrieve all links `<a>`. Then I access to style which return a CSSStyleDeclariotn object but I cant't access to cssText property to see if the link has "display: none". when I check on the console I have a empty element...

This is my code

```
   var numLink = 0;
   var numLinkHidden = 0;

   for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item-content .list li a')) {

       numLink = numLink + 1;

       var linkStyle = a.style.cssText;

       if(linkStyle == "display: none;") {

          numLinkHidden = numLinkHidden + 1;
       }
  } 

  if( numLinkHidden == numLink){

      document.getElementById("messageAccordion").innerHTML = 'You have already added all Card available';

  }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the demo below:

```js
const list = document.querySelector(".list");
const linkCount = document.querySelectorAll(".link").length;

list.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // stop the default click action happening e.g. navigating to a new URL
  event.preventDefault();

  // check to make sure the correct item was clicked
  const element = event.target.closest("li");
  if ( !element  || element.id == "messageAccordion") return;

  // hide the list item and do whatever add logic you want
  element.classList.add("hide");
  add(element);

  function add(element) {
  //place you code for adding here
    alert("adding element")
  }

  // check if the all the links have been clicked
  const hiddenCount = document.querySelectorAll(".hide").length;
  const message = document.querySelector("#messageAccordion");
  if (linkCount == hiddenCount && !message.textContent) {
    message.textContent = "You have already added all Card available";
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
  <a href="#" class="item-link item-content">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <div class="item-title">Menu Select</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="accordion-item-content">
    <div class="list">
      <ul >
        <li id="messageAccordion"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="link" id="linkAd1">
            <div class="item-media"><i class="f7-icons">add_round_fill </i></div>
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title">Add Canel 1</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="" class="link" id="linkAd2">
            <div class="item-media"><i class="f7-icons">add_round_fill</i></div>
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title">Add Card 2</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="" class="link button-round" id="linkAllevamenti">
            <div class="item-media"><i class="f7-icons">add_round_fill </i></div>
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title">add Card 3</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>

        <!-- other <li><li> element -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--accordion-content-->
</div>
<!--accordion-->
```

It works by first calculating how many elements with the class of `.link` there are in the document and then placing the function to handle click events on the element with the class of `.list` (I removed the javascript from your HTML as making use of [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) makes things easier to maintain).

The function that responds to the click event adds a class of `.hide` to all `li` elements that are clicked followed by running an `add(element)` function that can do whatever logic you want.

Lastly, the function checks if all the elements with a class of `.hide` is equal to the number of links on the page and if so, add your message but if the message has already been added then do nothing.

[You can read more about events here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: It works, thank you a lot for the demo and the good explanation! :D

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery, you can do something like this :

```
if( $(item).is(':visible') ){
   /* do something ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of suggestions:

1) you misspelled .innerHTML :p

2) why not target document.querySelectorAll('.link')

a) my reasoning to this is that you're trying to access an element with the following classes 
      - accordion-item-content, list, li, a

b) you could try document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item-content > .list > li > a') to match all anchor tags that lie below lists that are under a .list classed element which then in turn are under a .accordion-item-content element

If you can then retrieve the element as a non null entity then,
this may be what you're looking for!

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_csstext.asp

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions :) but if I use '.accordion-item-content .link' the problem remain

Comment: Not a problem! :)

Have you tried just '.link' by itself?

JQuery is also a life saver too!